# Anyone familiar with firewall CMD code. Or how to stop ISP

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, isp, throttling

Looking on a website and they say that this helps to stop isp from throttling your speeds. Is this true?

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”StopThrottling” dir=in action=block remoteip=173.194.55.0/24,206.111.0.0/16 enable=yes
```

Comment: Where did you read this? What do you think you will gain by blocking a small part of Google's network? Your ISP, of course, does any throttling from *their* end. There's little you're going to be able to do about that.

Answer (score 1):

That firewall rule will do nearly nothing that you want it to do, unless you want to block Google and Youtube.

- `dir=in` specifies the rule is for incoming data
- `action=block` specifies that the packets are to be blocked
- `remoteip=` gives a list of IPs to apply the rule to

  - `173.194.55.0/24` is an IP group assigned to Google LLC: https://ipinfo.io/AS15169/173.194.48.0/20-173.194.55.0/25
  - `206.111.0.0/16` is assigned to Verizon: https://ipinfo.io/AS2828/206.111.0.0/16

There is some [anecdotal evidence from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/teenagers/comments/4xxqkq/block_2061110016_in_your_firewall_and_youtube/) that blocking the 206.111.0.0 address block will stop you receiving data from Verizon proxies and therefore get your video streams directly from Youtube without their slow proxies, but I'm not sure why you would then go on to block all Google IP addresses as well.

If you are not a Verizon customer then all this rule will do is block Google services and stop you communicating with people through Verizon.

It will not magically improve your internet speed.